# How to compare alternating rows in CSV using RUBY

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a data set that consists thousand of rows. I would like to count how many times an alarm toggle between ALARM_OPENED and ALARM_NORMALIZED

Here is a data sample. The Alarm toggle twice and hence ideally the `count = 2`

[image]

The issue now is I cannot figure how to

1) compare  ALARM _OPENED and ALARM_NORMALIZED for the event type

2) To compare the difference in time between the change in event (the toggling should happen within a time frame of two seconds.)

```
count = 0 
#loop this 
if event_type[0] = 'ALARM_OPENED' 
  if event_type[1] = 'ALARM_NORMALIZED'
    #time[0] - time[1] = 2 seconds
    count = count + 1
  end
end

p count
```

Comment: Paste relevant code fragment into your question instead of pasting screenshot.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: Now the code doesn't have line 24

Comment: Does the event_type always transition from ALARM_OPENED to ALARM_NORMALIZED and than either back to ALARM_OPENED or to the final event_type of ALARM_CLOSED?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ah my bad. Line 24 was basically #time[0] - time[1] = 2 seconds

Comment: @Stefan Yes, the purpose is to count how many times it transit from ALARM_OPENED to ALARM_NORMALIZED

Comment: And does your example code work accordingly? (hard to say without some context)

Comment: @Stefan The comparison I’m making in my sample code assumes it would be ALARM_OPENED, ALARM_NORMALIZED, ALARM_OPENED, ALARM_NORMALIZED. I would like it to compare row.next until it meets the toggle criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that you always have a bunch of OPENED/NORMALIZED pairs, you can slice the array into pairs:

```
event_type.each_slice(2) do |opened, normalized|
  break unless normalized # unpaired event at the end
  # whatever you want to do with the two events here
end
```

Comment: I've edited the data sample. I was wondering if your code could be altered to identify the toggling of alarm from opened to normalized?