# Counting changes in a nested array

Tags: arrays, ruby, count

The status of an alarm is shown in this array. 
Time format is as follows HH:MM:SS

```
[["red",    "00:00:00"],
 ["orange", "00:00:02"],
 ["green",  "00:00:05"],
 ["red",    "00:00:07"],
 ["green",  "00:00:27"],
 ["red",    "00:00:28"],
 ["green",  "00:00:29"]]
```

I would like to count the number of times "red" is followed by "green" within a time period of 10 seconds.

```
Step 1: Look for red

Step 2: IF Not last item 
           Compare with next item on array
        ELSE Go to Step 4  

Step 3: IF green, 
           time_difference = green_time - red_time 
           IF time_difference <= 10 seconds
                    count = count + 1
                    Go to Step 1
           ELSE Go to Step 1
         ELSE Go to Step 2

Step 4: Print Count
```

The count should be 2

Comment: @sawa I would like to count the number of times "red" is followed by "green" within a time period of 10 seconds.

Comment: How do you get the time?

Comment: @sawa The array consists of [color, time]

Comment: How is `time` in `[color, time]` converted to the time?

Comment: @sawa Keith has written an answer below,  It does a conversion there

Comment: Don't rely on others to state your question. State your question by yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. The array has [color, time], you want to know how did I get the `time` format in the array?

Comment: For example, how does `"00:00:00"` express time?

Comment: @sawa I've edited the question. It's HH:MM:SS

Comment: Seems like you keep asking the same question [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882247/how-to-compare-alternating-rows-in-csv-using-ruby) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897581/subtract-time-from-csv-using-ruby) [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48899497/counting-changes-in-an-array) again (with a varying amount of information).

Comment: _"I have no idea why people are down voting"_ – well, your question doesn't show any attempts to solve the problem yourself. To me it sounds like "here's the algorithm now turn that into Ruby code, please". But Stack Overflow doesn't work like that, this is not a code writing service.

Comment: @Stefan I get it now. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Stefan it was never my intention to use stack overflow as a code writing service. I am trying and I did show some of my codes in my earlier questions. I do want to point out that I’m new to Ruby/programming and I wish the community would be more encouraging rather than down voting what seems to be “not intelligent” to them

Comment: @JoshuaNg downvoting can be very frustrating, but remember that the question is being rated, not you. Downvotes are an indicator that your problem statement is unclear to others or seems to lack effort.

Comment: @Stefan Alright, I’ll keep that in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result =
  input.map do |k, t|
    [k, DateTime.parse(t)]
  end.each_with_object(prev: nil, count: 0) do |(k, t), acc|
    case k
                  # keep the time of the previous occurrence of "red" 
    when "red" then acc[:prev] = t    
    when "green" 
                        # seconds 
      acc[:count] += 1 if 24.0 * 60 * 60 * (t - acc[:prev]) < 10
      acc[:prev] = nil  
    end  
  end[:count]

  p(result)
  #⇒ 2
```

Comment: `p count` doesnt work. How can I observe the count result?

Comment: Assign the whole outcome to the variable. Why do you expect `p(count)` to ever work?

Comment: To be honest, your code is amazing and mind blowing at the same time. It's hard to comprehend which is what and so I don't know where to get the outcome. But I'm loving it.

Comment: I have been following your answers, It's simply awesome! You know how to cascade the function efficiently! May I know how many years you have been in Ruby?

Comment: @RAJ 5 years and I am not in Ruby anymore.

Comment: @mudasobwa Oh okay,Great! I have been using WATIR so I know of little ruby, but I wanted to write code like you atleast in near future, what do you suggest me to do? What I observed between other language and Ruby is, In Other language how efficiently you use logic but in Ruby how effiently we use predefined methods , my understanding is correct ?

Comment: @RAJ I am not a guru by any means; the only thing I can suggest: write more code. You’ll start to feel how to do the best—after the first megabyte of written garbage.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

A = [
  ["red",    "00:00:00"],
  ["orange", "00:00:02"],
  ["green",  "00:00:05"],
  ["red",    "00:00:07"],
  ["green",  "00:00:27"],
  ["red",    "00:00:28"],
  ["green",  "00:00:29"]
]


def seconds(string) # hh:mm:ss
  hours, minutes, seconds = string.split(':').map(&:to_i)
  hours * 60 * 60 + minutes * 60 + seconds
end


def seconds_diff_relative_to_next(array, i)
  seconds(array[i+1].last) - seconds(array[i].last)
end


reds_and_greens = A.select { |a| a.first == 'red' || a.first == 'green' }
puts "Reds and greens:\n\n"
p reds_and_greens; puts;


matches = (0..(reds_and_greens.size - 2)).select do |i|
  if reds_and_greens[i].first == 'red' && reds_and_greens[i+1].first == 'green'
    seconds = seconds_diff_relative_to_next(reds_and_greens, i)
    puts "#{i}, red -> green, difference in seconds = #{seconds}"
    seconds <= 10
  end
end


puts
matches.each do |match|
  puts "Match: #{match}: #{reds_and_greens[match..match+1].inspect}"
end


=begin

Produces:

Reds and greens:

[["red", "00:00:00"], ["green", "00:00:05"], ["red", "00:00:07"], ["green", "00:00:27"], ["red", "00:00:28"], ["green", "00:00:29"]]

0, red -> green, difference in seconds = 5
2, red -> green, difference in seconds = 20
4, red -> green, difference in seconds = 1

Match: 0: [["red", "00:00:00"], ["green", "00:00:05"]]
Match: 4: [["red", "00:00:28"], ["green", "00:00:29"]]

=end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your given problem

```
array = [
  ["red",    "00:00:00"],
  ["orange", "00:00:02"],
  ["green",  "00:00:05"],
  ["red",    "00:00:07"],
  ["green",  "00:00:27"],
  ["red",    "00:00:28"],
  ["green",  "00:00:29"]
]

# iterating over first to second last element of array. Skipping the last element because we want to compare every element with its successor.

selected_result_set = array[0..-2].select.with_index do |arr, index|
  # first comparing if current element (array) contains 'red' and its successor contains 'green'
  if arr[0] == 'red' && array[index + 1][0] == 'green'
    # comparing time difference here
    (DateTime.parse(arr[1]).to_time - DateTime.parse(array[index + 1][1]).to_time) <= 10
  end
end

# selected result will consist of the array of 'red' value which passes our condition
selected_result_set.count
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `Time` class has no `parse` method.

Comment: @mudasobwa Yeah. Mixed some rails with ruby :P
Code updated

Comment: `DateTime` ruby class indeed has `parse` method.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Sure, `Time` has `parse`. Just not in the core. It's in the stdlib. You have to `require 'time'` first.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev indeed.

Comment: I think we can use `DateTime.parse` and `to_time` together for this purpose